# How to set click listener on list item in material ui in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to apply click listener on list item in `material-ui` in `reactjs`. I have set `onTouchTap` for it as below:

```
  _renderTodos() {
    return this.state.todos.map(event => {
      return (
        <ListItem
          primaryText={event.text}
          key={event.id}
          style={{ width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}
          onTouchTap={this._handleListItemClick(event)}
        />
      );
    });
  }

  _handleListItemClick(item) {
    console.log("Clicked!!");
  }

render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <AppBarTest />
          <FloatingActionButton
            style={styles.fab}
            backgroundColor={colors.blue_color}
            onTouchTap={this.handleOpen}
          >
            <ContentAdd />
          </FloatingActionButton>
          <Dialog
            open={this.state.open}
            onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
            title={strings.dialog_create_note_title}
          >
            <TextField
              name="notetext"
              hintText="Note"
              style={{ width: "48%", float: "left", height: 48 }}
              defaultValue={this.state.noteVal}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onKeyPress={ev => {
                if (ev.key === "Enter") {
                  this.handleCreateNote();
                  ev.preventDefault();
                }
              }}
            />

            <div
              style={{
                width: "4%",
                height: "1",
                float: "left",
                visibility: "hidden"
              }}
            />

            <FlatButton
              label={strings.create_note}
              style={{ width: "48%", height: 48, float: "left" }}
              onTouchTap={this.handleCreateNote}
            />
          </Dialog>

          <List style={{ margin: 8 }}>
            {this._renderTodos()}
          </List>

        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on `ListItem` then it does not trigger `_handleListItemClick` method, instead when I click on any other component like `FlatButton` and `FloatingActionButton` then it triggers and print a message on console which I have in `_handleListItemClick`.

Can anyone help me what wrong I am doing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a `function` to `onTouchTap` event and that `function` will get called whenever you clicked on that item, but you are assigning a value by calling that `function` (you don't need to call that function), remove `()`.

Write it like this by using `arrow function`:

```
<ListItem
    primaryText={event.text}
    key={event.id}
    style={{ width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}
    onTouchTap={(event) => this._handleListItemClick(event)}
/>
```

Or another way:

```
<ListItem
    primaryText={event.text}
    key={event.id}
    style={{ width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}
    onTouchTap={this._handleListItemClick.bind(this)}
/>
```

`_handleListItemClick` function:

```
_handleListItemClick(event){
   console.log('clicked');
}
```

Comment: why onTouchTap and not onClick?